# Transferring a macro embedded PPT ribbon

Tags: vba, add-in, ribbon

Within Powerpoint 2010 I have customised a tab on ribbon with both standard and custom macro buttons using 'customize the ribbon'.

In an attempt to share this ribbon with friends I have exported the ribbon as an .exportedUI file and saved the presentation as a macro enabled template.

When I open up any file called (Presentation1) the buttons work fine as the name for the macros are 'Presentation1'!macro#. If I then save as or open another blank (Presentation 2) the buttons produce the error:

"The macro could not be found or has been disabled because of your security settings"

The problem appears to be with the name of the macro that is associated with the button.

Is it possible to mix custom with standard buttons on an exportable ribbon? Or will I have to create an add-in that produces a new tab then replicate the standard buttons required? I know it is possible to do this in Excel and in Word but in Powerpoint it appears not to be?

Comment: It would be most helpful if you can post your XML from the Custom UI editor, and also a sample of code from your macros.  I've done some ribbon extensibility (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860236/is-there-a-way-to-disable-commandbar-controls-in-powerpoint-vba) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664489/customizing-the-powerpoint-ribbon-at-run-time)) and might be able to help.